# How to perform a power analysis for the following binomial Glmm?

Tags: regression, logistic

H0: There is no effect of treatment (Road vs control) on rat occupancy
 H1: Road has an effect on rat occupancy

```
Mod1 <- glmer(Rat.Present ~ Treatment * Set.distance + (1|Site/Trap.Night), data = df.sub1,
            family = binomial)
summary(Mod1)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Rat.Present ~ Treatment * Set.distance + (1 | Site/Trap.Night)
   Data: df.sub1

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1481.7   1589.3   -722.9   1445.7     2889 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5000 -0.2926 -0.2491 -0.2168  5.8191 

Random effects:
 Groups          Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Trap.Night:Site (Intercept) 0.14220  0.3771  
 Site            (Intercept) 0.03856  0.1964  
Number of obs: 2907, groups:  Trap.Night:Site, 42; Site, 7

Fixed effects:
                              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                   -2.55908    0.33450  -7.650    2e-14 ***

TreatmentRoad                  0.19659    0.42991   0.457   0.6475    
TreatmentRoad:Set.distance30  -0.36999    0.57663  -0.642   0.5211    
TreatmentRoad:Set.distance60   0.61724    0.65301   0.945   0.3445    
TreatmentRoad:Set.distance90   0.09708    0.59444   0.163   0.8703    
TreatmentRoad:Set.distance120 -0.45507    0.59755  -0.762   0.4463    
TreatmentRoad:Set.distance150  0.19878    0.59059   0.337   0.7364    
TreatmentRoad:Set.distance180  0.83808    0.56708   1.478   0.1394    
TreatmentRoad:Set.distance210  0.06726    0.54020   0.125   0.9009     

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

`Rat.Present` is a binary (Yes/No)
`Treatment` is categorical predictor variable of `road` or `control`
`Set.distance` is a categorical predictor variable of the distance `0`, `30`, `60`, `90` $\dots$ `210` m at both treatments.

My random effects are the sites I sampled. At each site I sampled 6 nights, that is why `Trap.Night` is nested in `Site`.

Question 2. How do I obtain the effect size since it is a binomial data? I have 8 sites (3 controls; 5 roads). N=72 per site At a significant level of 0.05